# In AppleScript how to you retrieve the name of the current active worksheet?

Tags: excel, macos, applescript

It seems like a simple question, but much use of Google has not yielded the answer.

Consider the following code...

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set strActiveWorkSheet to active sheet of active workbook

    display dialog strActiveWorkSheet
end tell
```

This code does not work. It seems that the set command is setting strActiveWorkSheet to a object that represents the Active Worksheet.

Maybe I'm on the wrong track here but the questions remains...

How to I retrieve the name of the current active Excel worksheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny... your question is the answer... just get its name. You're right. You have an object the way its written and the object has properties, one of which is "name". In other words change this line...

```
set strActiveWorkSheet to name of active sheet of active workbook
```

To see all of the properties of the object try this...

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    return properties of active sheet of active workbook
end tell
```

You can access any of those properties just by asking for it. Good luck.

Comment: Can you show me how to reference the name element of the worksheet object?  Is it something like strActiveWorkSheet[Name]?